# Php preg_match apache custom logs

Tags: php, apache, logging, preg-match

Hello I have a logs example:

```
x.xx.xxx.xx - username [06/Mar/2014:14:22:24 +0400] "GET /folder/folder1/file.php HTTP/1.1" 200 246
```

I use [apache-log-parser.php](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2596-PHP-Parse-Apache-log-files-in-the-common-log-format.html)

Standard pattern for preg_match log file is wrong.

```
preg_match("/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/", $line, $matches);
```

Please help with `reg_exp` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the last parts:

```
preg_match("/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+)$/", $line, $matches);
```